# Unable to run Apache Spark related unit test in SBT - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, unit-testing, jetty, sbt, apache-spark

I have a simple unit test that uses a `SparkContext`. I am able to run the unit test from within IntelliJ Idea without any problems. However when trying to run the same test from the SBT shell I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/bio/SocketConnector
    at org.apache.spark.HttpServer.org$apache$spark$HttpServer$$doStart(HttpServer.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.HttpServer$$anonfun$1.apply(HttpServer.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.HttpServer$$anonfun$1.apply(HttpServer.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1446)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.HttpFileServer.initialize(HttpFileServer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:118)
    at com.company.myservice.merging.Merger.<init>(Merger.scala:16)
    at com.company.myservice.merging.MergerTest.<init>(MergerTest.scala:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:641)
    at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:84)
    at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:94)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
    at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:212)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
    at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:229)
    at sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:211)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is what my build.scala looks like:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import org.scalatra.sbt._
import org.scalatra.sbt.PluginKeys._
import com.mojolly.scalate.ScalatePlugin._
import ScalateKeys._
import com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.PluginKeys._
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.WebPlugin._
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._
import sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys._


object myservice extends Build {
  val Organization = "com.company"
  val Name = "myservice"
  val Version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  val ScalaVersion = "2.10.4"
  val ScalatraVersion = "2.3.0"

  // settings for sbt-assembly plugin
  val myAssemblySettings = assemblySettings ++ Seq(

    // handle conflicts during assembly task
    mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) {
      (old) => {
        case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
      }
    },

    // copy web resources to /webapp folder
    resourceGenerators in Compile <+= (resourceManaged, baseDirectory) map {
      (managedBase, base) =>
        val webappBase = base / "src" / "main" / "webapp"
        for {
          (from, to) <- webappBase ** "*" x rebase(webappBase, managedBase / "main" / "webapp")
        } yield {
          Sync.copy(from, to)
          to
        }
    }
  )

  lazy val project = Project (
    "myapplication",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ScalatraPlugin.scalatraWithJRebel ++
      SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings ++
      scalateSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      port in container.Configuration := 8000,
      resolvers ++= Seq (Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
        "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
        "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"),

      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % ScalaVersion,
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % ScalaVersion,

        "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",

        "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.6",

        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
        "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.8",

        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.1",

        "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.16",
        "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6-M4",

        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container;compile",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),

        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.8.5",

        "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "0.9.1",

        "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-auth" % "2.3.0",

        // RDBMS-Mysql
        "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "latest.release",
        "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.175",

        // Geolocation
        "com.javadocmd" % "simplelatlng" % "1.3.0",

        // Spark and Mllib
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.1.0", 
        // Lucene
        "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "4.8.1",
        // for Porter Stemmer
        "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-analyzers-common" % "4.8.1",
        // Guava for the dictionary
        "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "17.0",

        // CSV lib
        "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

      ),
      scalateTemplateConfig in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile){ base =>
        Seq(
          TemplateConfig(
            base / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "templates",
            Seq.empty,  /* default imports should be added here */
            Seq(
              Binding("context", "_root_.org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext", importMembers = true, isImplicit = true)
            ),  /* add extra bindings here */
            Some("templates")
          )
        )
      }
    )
  ).settings(myAssemblySettings:_*)
    .settings( parallelExecution in ThisBuild := false : _*)
}
```

I tried adding all the following dependencies to my build.scala with no success:

```
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-http" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-io" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-security" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-util" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a testing setup on IntelliJ using the spark-1.2.0 source, but I'm stuck getting LocalSparkContext and friends imported. The jar that comes with the complied sources ( spark-assembly-1.2.0-hadoop2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar in my case ) does not have test sources in it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 9.2.1 does not contain `org/eclipse/jetty/server/bio/SocketConnector`

It was removed from Jetty 9 entirely.

You also have a mix of Jetty versions.

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container;compile",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container;test",
```

Either upgrade your testing libraries (spark?) to support Jetty 9, or downgrade your version of Jetty to 8.1.8.

*History:* The work in Jetty 9 to support SPDY / NPN / ALPN / HTTP2 meant the entire connector architecture underwent an overhaul.  First to go were all blocking connectors, leaving only nio connectors.  Then, in order to support all of the new protocol negotiation steps, all of the connectors were merged into a new [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html).  The ServerConnector had configuration to specify your encryption, protocols, desired negotiation order and fallbacks.

*Note: Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are near EOL (will be official at end of 2014).*

*See http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html*

Comment: Downgrade to Jetty 7.x proved successful